# Помогите реализовать SQL запрос фильтра на сайте

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток, есть 4 таблицы. Products, Model, Product_model_relation, Brand.
    `Products 
id 
title`

`Model 
id 
title
brand_id`

`Product_model_relation 
id 
product_id 
model_id`

`Brand 
id 
title`

Фильтр осуществляется по брендам. Сами данные забираю с помощью Ajax при изменении select option.
[image: Фильтр по брендам]

Возникли проблемы с реализацией правильного SQL запроса, чтобы при выборе бренда, выборкой получить все продукты, данного бренда.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой `SQL` запрос

```
SELECT p.*
FROM `Brand` AS b
INNER JOIN `Model` AS m ON m.brand_i = b.id
INNER JOIN `Product_model_relation` AS pmr ON pmr.model_id = m.id
INNER JOIN `Products` AS p ON p.id = pmr.product_id
WHERE b.id = <:id>
```